# Set Use Default Value for all categories attributes Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, category-attribute

I have around 1260 categories.If i switch the store view , the all attributes have own value.But i want to set the all attribute values as parent main store view value.
I can not open each category and checked the Use Default Value checkbox.
So can you give me any hint how can i checked this checkbox using programmatically or sql Query.

Please see this screenshot.!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For categories i ran the following query and it worked.**

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_entity_text` where store_id = 1;
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_entity_datetime` where store_id = 1;
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_entity_decimal` where store_id = 1;
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_entity_int` where store_id = 1;
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar` where store_id = 1;
```

Comment: Great!! it works for me. Thanks.. Keep it up bro

Answer (score 1):

You need to change in database OR create PHP script to update database value.

Comment: Can you please explain me in brief?

Comment: Yes, you need to create PHP script for update values for all categories in Database.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the `Use Default` checkbox at all! On several platforms running `2.1.16` there is no checkbox to restore the Default values. In the Release notes I can't find anything about it. What Magento version were you running in the screenshot?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.! I have solved issue. jaimin's answer is working for me.